# Is there any API to support creating a new question on stackoverflow?

Tags: support, api-v2

I know there is api for stackoverflow.

It looks like the APIs are read-only, supporting the Get/Search operation.

Is there any API to support creating a new question on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the official APIs do not contain support for asking new questions.  They do not currently contain support for anything write related (ie, edits, answers, tagging, users, etc) at all.